# How can I install pyplot package in pycharm?

Tags: python

I am facing a version issue in here. Can anyone guide me how to resolve it?

```
error:
Collecting pyplot

  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyplot (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pyplot
You are using pip version 18.1, however version 19.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: You might want to consider upgrading with the command `python -m pip install -upgrade pip` or am I missing something completely?

Comment: thanks geisterfurz007 but i have already done with upgrading pip 19.1.I need to install a package of pyplot in pycharm but it gives me an above mentioned error of 18.1. I can't understand the issue actually?

Comment: Check VPN connection. If you are connected try disconnecting and then installing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pyplot` is under `matplotlib`, try `pip install matplotlib`.

Here's a simple example of how to use it:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()
```